# JavaScript Object.prototype by value

Tags: javascript, prototype, object, prototypejs

I want to do something like `Object.prototype.dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();`, but I want every new object to have it's own `dataTransfer`.  How do I do this?

For example, if I do

```
var a = new Object();
var b = new Object();
Object.prototype.dataTransfer = new Object();
a.dataTransfer.prop = 1;
b.dataTransfer.prop = 2;
```

I want `a.dataTransfer.prop` to still be 1, not 2.

For context, I'm trying to hack WebKit and IE so that the .dataTransfer object of the drag and drop events works appropriately.

Comment: On a side note, you should **never** extend `Object.prototype`.

Comment: ^ If you use someone's (another person) crappy code that can't handle it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you'd add it in the constructor, but since you're wanting to extend a host object (HTMLDomElement), what you want isn't really possible. However, if you broaden the definition of your problem beyond specific implementation details like this, there may be another way,
 such as a library with a different (possible) user facing API that works differently depending on which browser it is in, successfully abstracting the browser and supplying a uniform API.